# PostQuantum Lattice-based schemes and Nguyen-Regev like attacks

Tags: public-key, signature, key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

As far as I know NTRUSign is considered to be a Post-Quantum scheme but it's vulnerable to the [Nguyen-Regev attack](http://www.szydlo.com/ntru-revised-full02.pdf) that allow to recover private key when there is an access to signature oracle (as it stated in the original paper, 400 message-signature pairs are enough).

After that paper some improvements [were proposed and cracked](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00864359) and now NTRUSign seems to be broken.

Do other lattice-based Post-Quantum schemes suffer from the attack by Nguyen-Regev or similar attacks? Signature and key agreement schemes should also be considered.

Comment: If you vote down please describe in comments the reason for that.

Comment: Just to add: I'm not sure that *all* NTRU signature proposals are necessarily broken, see for instance https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/471. Yes, the initial attempts were flawed, but I suppose the standard way to defend against these breaks (rejection sampling) can also be applied to NTRU signatures. Maybe @zhenfei zhang can shed more light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NTRUSign does not have a security reduction of the type "if one can break the scheme then one can find short vectors in some lattice."  There are several other lattice schemes that do have such a reduction, and are therefore unaffected (as far as we know) by the Nguyen-Regev attack.  If they were affected, then we would have a better algorithm fro finding short vectors in lattices.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with lattice-based crypto and I used to think NTRUSign has reduction to SVP, now it's clear.